# Action is triggered thrice on a single event

Tags: javascript, jsp, event-handling, struts2, action

This is kind of simple (I know) but yet I cant figure it out.

**What is happening:**

I have a jsp on which a button triggers an action (which deletes a particular record in db). But what I have observed is that the action is triggered thrice when the button is clicked, causing an error message even though the record is deleted. There are two 'divs'(parent-child) on the jsp page(see the code below). The button is in the child one.

**What I found out:**

when I remove the parent div (which makes the child one, parent) everything works fine (of-course except for the function that the parent div was performing). I read this post :

[Event handler triggered twice instead of once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727313/)

which suggested 'event bubbling' problem. I tried adding `stopPropagation();` But that did not workout either.

Maybe something simple is escaping my eye. Please help.

Here is my code for jsp:

```
<s:url id="scriptURL" action="getContactInfo" />
<sd:div href="%{scriptURL}" listenTopics="getContactInfo" formId="contactInfo" showLoadingText="false" preload="false">
    <s:url id="scriptURL1"  action='delContactInfo'/>
    <sd:div href="%{scriptURL1}" listenTopics="delContactInfo" formId="contactInfo" showLoadingText="false" preload="false">

        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:actionmessage/>
        <s:form name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" action="editContactInfo">

            <sd:autocompleter id="contact"  name="contact"  label="Full Name " autoComplete="false" searchType="substring" list="contactList"  valueNotifyTopics="getContactInfo"/>
            <sd:autocompleter id="customer" name="customer" label="Company "   autoComplete="false" searchType="substring" list="customerList" valueNotifyTopics="getContactInfo"/>
            //////other controls////////


            //////other controls////////

            <s:submit id="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" align="center" onclick="saveEvent(event);"/>

        </s:form>

        <s:submit id="del" name="del" align="center" value="Delete" onclick="deleteEvent(event);"/>

    </sd:div>

</sd:div>
```

The JS file:

```
function deleteEvent(e)
{
    alert('Delete the selected account !!');
    alert('Are you sure?');
    dojo.event.topic.publish('delContactInfo');

    event = e || window.event;
    if ('bubbles' in event) {   // all browsers except IE before version 9
        if (event.bubbles) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert('1');
        }else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
             event.cancelBubble = true;
            alert('2');
        }
    }else{
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        alert('3');
    }
}

function saveEvent(e){
    alert('Do you want to save the changes you made?');

    event = e || window.event;
    if ('bubbles' in event) {   // all browsers except IE before version 9
        if (event.bubbles) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        }else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }else{
        event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

I guess the problem lies somewhere here only. Because after this action is called which is doing its job. Its just that it is being called thrice. But if you feel additional information is required, please comment.

Thanks!!

Edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do this inline use something like this:

```
<prior stuff here>; var e = arguments[0] || window.event; e.stopPropagation();
```

It is much better to put the code in an external function and call it like this:

```
onclick="handleEvent(event);"


function handleEvent(e)
{

   // function code

   // then
  event = e || window.event;
  if ('bubbles' in event) {   // all browsers except IE before version 9
     if (event.bubbles) {
       event.stopPropagation();
     }
     else {  // Internet Explorer before version 9
       event.cancelBubble = true;
     }      
   }
}
```

Example taken from various places including http://help.dottoro.com/ljgfjsxd.php

---

For your newest code I would suggest this:

```
   <s:form name="contactInfo" id="contactInfo" action="editContactInfo">

        <sd:autocompleter id="contact"  name="contact"  label="Full Name " autoComplete="false" searchType="substring" list="contactList"  valueNotifyTopics="getContactInfo"/>
        <sd:autocompleter id="customer" name="customer" label="Company "   autoComplete="false" searchType="substring" list="customerList" valueNotifyTopics="getContactInfo"/>
        //////other controls////////


        //////other controls////////

        <s:submit id="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" align="center" onclick="saveEvent(event);"/>
        <s:submit id="del" name="del" align="center" value="Delete"   onclick="deleteEvent(event);"/>
    </s:form>
```

Note: both submit buttons are in the same form.

Comment: Hi, I tried this just now. The problem still persists. Any more advice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, its still not working. I have tried some modifications in this, taking some inputs from Google. But it has made only one difference, the 3 action execution threads are now executing one after another, rather than simultaneously as earlier.

Comment: @kanish : please update the source in the question so I know what you are doing.

Comment: Hi I have updated the page source and added the new js file that I am now using for writing java scripts separately.

Comment: Adding one more thing- notice the alert boxes I have setup in the js?  Only the alert box with '1' pops up and only once.

Comment: @kanishk does adding `return false;` to the end of the functions help? or try `onclick="saveEvent(event); return false;"` It depends on the javascript emited by the backend.

Comment: This just empties the values that were selected in all the controls on the page. Thanks I had been looking for a neat way to do this too!!

Comment: But my original problem remains the same. I guess maybe something re-triggers the action when the page is loading again, because I noticed that if I use stopPropagation() before notifying the topic (for calling the action), nothing happens except for the two alerts that I have setup. The action does not get called.

Comment: I tried including the 2nd button in the form, tried using normal html button instead, in and out of the form. Still no help... :(

Comment: Hey Hogan, one thing, can I call the action I am calling through the div, directly through java script I have written for on-click. That would solve my problem as well. Otherwise I will be forced to create a separate page for deleting.

Comment: Try a new question for this... I don't understand and would need to see code.

Comment: OK Thanks for your effort Hogan.

Answer (score 0):

pls. refer below link and use  tag which is inbuild tag provided by struts2.

[How to restrict double click on button in struts /Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135713/how-to-restrict-double-click-on-button-in-struts-java)

Comment: This link talks about how to negate the effect of clicking the button twice. My problem is that only one click is causing action execution 3 times. Also notice that when I remove one div everything works fine...as I mentioned in my question.